# Axon - How to get @QueryHandler handle method to return a k,v Map

Tags: axon

I need to return a k,v map

```
Map<String,UserProfile>
```

Similar to how I query for a List.

```
queryGateway.query(q, ResponseTypes.multipleInstancesOf(UserProfile.class)
```

That works with a handler that returns a map.

```
@QueryHandler
Map<String, UserProfile> handle(UserProfileQuery query) {
    return userProfileRepository.getUserProfiles(query.getUserIds());
}
```

Using Axon 4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment (meaning version 4.3.1 of framework), the answer is rather simple Stephen.
You cannot return a `Map<K, V>` directly from an `@QueryHandler` annotated function.
It's currently an issue on Axon Framework's GitHub page, which you can find [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/1257).

Most pragmatic solution for now, is to provide a wrapper class containing the `Map<K, V>` you want to return.
Or, likely, a `Collection` of *entries* is what you are looking for, as you are suggesting to use the `ResponseTypes#multipleInstancesOf(Class)` function.
It's the *entry* object you'd have to create yourself in this case.

Hope this helps!